# wso2 - esb payloadfactory - get inner element

Tags: wsdl, wso2, esb, payload

I have this input:

```
<request>
   <element1>
        <field1>Text1</field1
   </element1>
   <element2>
        <field2>Text1</field2>
   </element2>
</request>
```

what I've done is:

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:req="http://request.com" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
                <req:MyRequest>
                    <req:MyElement1>$1</req:MyElement1>
                    <req:MyElement2>$2</req:MyElement2>
                </rqe:MyRequest>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//req:request/req:element1/req1:field1"
             xmlns:req="http://request.com/" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
        <arg evaluator="xml"
             expression="//req:request/req:element2/req1:field2"
             xmlns:req="http://request.com/" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

I tried this on ESB but I've this error

> The system cannot infer the transport information from the /services/

My question is: how can I put the deeper element "field1" to MyElement1 ?

Thanks in advance

BR
Claudio

Comment: Why do you use the namespaces 'req' & 'req1' in the xpath expressions defined into arg elements inside the payloadFactory, there is no namespace in your xml input ?  Note that req1 is not defined.   If you remove your payloadFactory (and replace it with a log level="full"), are you able to call your proxy service ?

Comment: As Jean-Michel is saying , your xPath is not valid. Could you paste your full request message

Comment: yes guys your right, I used the correct ns and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While searching on your error I have found a blog post saying how to handle the error you got.

http://charithaka.blogspot.com/2014/02/common-mistakes-to-avoid-in-wso2-esb-1.html

Please try out these solutions.